# Spring JsonPath contains in any order exception

Tags: java, spring, testing, jsonpath, hamcrest

I'm writing some integration tests with spring, and wanna check, that json from response contains all required data. See code:

```
@Test
public void getAll() throws Exception {
    String url = "/permissions/all";
    int size = 4;
    try {
        Set<String> permissions = RandomGenerator.randomStrings(size);
        initDb(permissions);
        mvc.perform(get(url).with(Users.PERMISSIONS_READ))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[?(@.name)].name", hasSize(size))) //ok
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[?(@.name)].name").value(containsInAnyOrder(permissions))); //exception
    } finally {
        dropDb();
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an exception here:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$[?(@.name)].name"

Expected: iterable over [<[b0ce9e8a-8b62-41f4-91b9-d9cf6ff96675, 7ebe3a4f-7864-4ea5-92b3-a5ad6f44bf42, 7df2fa88-b22f-4d33-91b2-f8b00813522f, 17b61119-c48c-4dff-ac9c-047eb3efcc43]>] in any order
 but: Not matched: "7df2fa88-b22f-4d33-91b2-f8b00813522f"
```

And the data from this response:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "7df2fa88-b22f-4d33-91b2-f8b00813522f" 
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "b0ce9e8a-8b62-41f4-91b9-d9cf6ff96675"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "7ebe3a4f-7864-4ea5-92b3-a5ad6f44bf42"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "17b61119-c48c-4dff-ac9c-047eb3efcc43"
}]
```

I know, that selector `$[?(@.name)].name` works fine, and returns a following result:

```
[
  "7df2fa88-b22f-4d33-91b2-f8b00813522f",
  "b0ce9e8a-8b62-41f4-91b9-d9cf6ff96675",
  "7ebe3a4f-7864-4ea5-92b3-a5ad6f44bf42",
  "17b61119-c48c-4dff-ac9c-047eb3efcc43"
]
```

`permissions` set is also correct and contains 4 strings as in the sample above.

Can somebody tell me please what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
Set<String> permissions = RandomGenerator.randomStrings(size);
initDb(permissions);
mvc.perform(get(url).with(Users.PERMISSIONS_READ))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[?(@.name)].name", hasSize(size))) //ok
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[?(@.name)].name").value(containsInAnyOrder(permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]))));
```

Or restated:

```
String[] permissions = RandomGenerator.randomStrings(size);
initDb(permissions);
mvc.perform(get(url).with(Users.PERMISSIONS_READ))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[?(@.name)].name", hasSize(size))) //ok
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[?(@.name)].name").value(containsInAnyOrder(permissions)));
```

Here's the signature of `containsInAnyOrder`:

```
public static <T> Matcher<Iterable<? extends T>> containsInAnyOrder(T... items)
```

So, it expects a varargs of the **same** type that you are asserting against. In your case you are asserting against the type `String` but you are supplying a `Set<String>` to `containsInAnyOrder` so the match between a String and a Set fails.